# CentOS won't start, Can't undo changes

Tags: linux, centos

I'm running CentOS 6.4 in a VMWare Player virtual machine.  I was trying to add two partitions to the file system.  First I used fdisk to add the partitions, then mke2fs, then I mounted the partitions.  Then I manually edited /etc/fstab, I added lines for the new partitions listed by blkid.

When I restarted, the OS is failing to start, it brings me to a terminal.  So I tried to undo the changes I made to the /etc/fstab file, but it's saying that everything is read only, even though I am root.  It won't let me remove the lines I added before to /etc/fstab.

Does anybody know how I can recover?  At least how to get the stupid thing to boot again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to remount the filesystem in `rw` mode:

```
mount -o rw,remount /
```

After that you can edit `/etc/fstab` and revert your changes, save the file and reboot.

Comment: You were right, I modified the file so the two new partitions will not be checked by fsck during boot up.  well the good news is I can boot again :D.  The bad news is that those partitions are still not getting mounted automatically.  When I do 'blkid' it does not list the two new partitions, even though 'fdisk -l /dev/sda' does list them.  If you could explain that to me to I would be very grateful.

Comment: @msknapp this is off-topic on this site. Post your questions about partitioning on serverfault or superuser. Make sure to include the output of `fdisk -l` and `blkid` in your question (on the other sites, NOT on this one). The users there will be able to help you better and get through the next steps!